# Test ad doesn't work on real device

Tags: android, admob

I want to show test interstitial ad in my app. But it works only on emulator. Real device log shows

```
I/Ads: Trying mediation network: 
I/Ads: Instantiating mediation adapter: com.google.DummyAdapter
I/Ads: No fill from any mediation ad networks.
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3
```

Here is an example just a button which calls ad.
I mostly copied code from https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("C8769F4DD80CE4D614D7ED92F6F49E61").build());


    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Load the next interstitial.
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("C8769F4DD80CE4D614D7ED92F6F49E61").build());
        }

    });
}

public void onClickBtn(View v)
{
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
    }
}
```

App has internet access permissions.

Please try it. I want to know whether it works on different devices. And if not where is a problem?

Comment: It would be great if you add your `AndroidManifest.xml` file in your question ?

Comment: I believe that code should work, and you're using the correct ad unit ID for a test interstitial. Can you tell us on what device you're loading the ad, and where in the world you're located? It's possible there's a problem with the test ad itself.

Comment: I use HTC One S device with cyanogenmod 12. I'm located in Russia.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, here is your problem, You don't need to add a test device when you are on a real device.

```
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("C8769F4DD80CE4D614D7ED92F6F49E61").build());


 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
               // Load the next interstitial.
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }

         });
       }

        myButton = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.myButtonn_button));
        //myButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
    }
    }
});
```

[Here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/admob/InterstitialExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/interstitialexample/MyActivity.java) is the example